# Why V2 is not dense in L2(R)?

Tags: density-function, wavelets

v2 contains all of constant
Piecewise function having compact supports with possible break on rational points denominators of 4.

Comment: Show your effort add the relevant context of the problem. Don't just put the question, here is nobody to serve you.

Comment: i want to add.. but i dont know how i can type mathemtical language... im new to here

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you know the answer?